# Django Template loop with variable

Tags: django, loops, templates, variables

I am having issue with django html variable so I made the below code which is working .

```
{%for field in instance %}
<tr>
<td width="250">
{{ field.Item }}
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value={{ field.P_640 }} >
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But at the view section I have variables and sometimes I am pushing filter value. P_640 and sometimes P_630  .How can I make my template to look to the colomn 1 instead of looking the field name like {{ field.P_640 }} , because it's not working when I push P_630. ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/ helps you do our logic in python

Comment: before asking I checked that filters and tags but couldn't find there what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
{% for field in instance %}
<tr>
 <td width="250">
  {{ field.Item }}
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" value="
   {% if field.P_640 }}
    {{ field.P_640 }}
   {% elif field.P_630 %}
    {{ field.P_630 }}
   {% endif %}
  ">
 </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Check for every value that could exist and then output it.

If there are multiple values, replace `{% elif %}` with `{% endif %}` `{% if %};`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.